Writing Cyrillic characters to a dbf file, react.js
Using the DBF library, I am trying to create a converter from a CSV file to DBF. The conversion should take place on the browser side. I have a problem - the Cyrillic characters are not displayed correctly in the created dbf file. I tried many options, but nothing worked.
csv file can have different encodings
  const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState(null);
  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        const text = e.target.result;
        const result = parse(text, { header: true });
        setCsvData(result.data);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  };
  const convertToDBF = () => {
    if (csvData) {
      try {
        const fields = Object.keys(csvData[0]).map(key => ({
          name: key,
          type: 'C',
          size: 10
        }));  
        const records = csvData.map(row => {
          const record = {};
          Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
            record[key] = row[key] ? row[key].toString() : ''; 
          });  
          for (const key in record) {
            if (typeof record[key] === 'string') {
              record[key] = iconv.encode(record[key], 'UTF-8'); 
            }     }
          return record;
        });
        const dbfBuffer = structure(records, fields);
        const blob = new Blob([dbfBuffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        saveAs(blob, 'output.dbf');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during DBF conversion:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      
      <input type="file" accept=".csv" onChange={handleFileUpload} />
      <button onClick={convertToDBF} disabled={!csvData}>to DBF</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

I tried to change the encodings. I expect a readable display of Cyrillic characters

CSV - Іванов Іван
dbf - 20=>2  20=


You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): print( 'Іванов'.encode( 'utf-16-be').decode( 'cp1251')) returns 20=>2. In some detail, Іванов is Unicode \u0406\u0432\u0430\u043D\u043E\u0432 interpreted byte-by-byte as \x04\x06\x04\x32\x04\x30\x04\x3D\x04\x3E\x04\x32, and there are unprintable ␄ (U+0004,  End Of Transmission) and ␆ (U+0006,  Acknowledge).

… Encoding of a .DBF file you can find in the 29th byte of the header, called  Language driver ID. Its possible values allows merely 8-bit encodings (no Unicode support)… Moreover, І (U+0406,  Cyrillic Capital Letter Byelorussian-Ukrainian I) isn't in any listed encoding (imho)…
